# How can i post my json from one php to another?

Tags: php

I would like to ask if this function exist `file_post_contents()`? Because `file_get_contents()` is perfectly working and I'm just curious if there is get, there should be post also?

Comment: `GET` in this case is not the request mode but the action being taken. The equivalent is `PUT`, e.g. `file_put_contents`.

Comment: In this instance `get` is not the same as `$_GET`, it means "retrieve" in this case. It's not using the `$_GET` superglobal, it's just *getting* the contents of a file. It's opposite is `file_put_contents()`

Comment: On that note, there is a bit of confusion on your title vs the content of your question...what does *"json from one php to another"* have to do with the misunderstanding of a function? What are you trying to do with json and where is that script?

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand. What is exactly your question is...

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I really do appreciate the help, and about the question, I'm really sorry, I am trying to post json file from my php to another  by his url. I did used file_get_content() before to get the contents of his json file and now I'm trying to use post function. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: If you are just sending a variable then you can just return the json_encode of the value or you can create a method for it and the return the value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to have a post function when there is a get, `file_get_content()` is similar function to `file()`, the only difference is it returns string, the opposite function may be `file_put_content()` because `file_get_content()' pull the file data and`file_put_content()` push data.

Of course you can build `file_post_content()` like [Admin eHow Does](https://www.adminsehow.com/2011/05/file_post_contents-php-function/), And may be you would like to do some research before asking here, maybe this [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/) come helpfull to you.